# How to hide/show elements in DropDownList in View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have 5 Dropdownlist with the same elements. The next step is to hide element (which is picked in first dropdownlist) in others dropdownlists.

For example: I would pick value "Speed" from first DropDownList and I won't show in others dropdowns.

I checked a lot of solutions with jQuery, but it nothing worked.

Below first two DropDownLists:

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstParameter, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstParameter, new SelectList(ViewBag.list), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstParameter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondParameter, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecondParameter, new SelectList(ViewBag.list), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SecondParameter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use JavaScript function on event of dropdown "OnChange" for option change

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma How can I hide precise option of DropDownList? `($("#select2").val('Speed')).hide();` is not working :(

Comment: Ok. I did it. 
`$("#select2 option[value='" + this.value + "']").hide();`

Comment: Perfect :) Now You have solution